# aws_key_pair.auth: Error import KeyPair: InvalidKey.Format: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format

Tags: openssh, terraform-provider-aws

terraform to create an EC2 instance and use a public key to login to EC2 instance is not working.
aws_key_pair.auth: Error import KeyPair: InvalidKey.Format: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format

## this is part of the main.tf to create a keypair

```
    main.tf
    
    resource "aws_key_pair" "auth" {
      key_name   = "${var.key_name}"
      public_key = "${file(var.public_key_path)}"
    }
```

## declaring the variable

```
    variable.tf
    
    variable "public_key_path" {
      description = <<DESCRIPTION
    Path to the SSH public key to be used for authentication.
    Ensure this keypair is added to your local SSH agent so provisioners can
    connect.
    Example: ~/.ssh/terraform.pub
    DESCRIPTION
      default = "~/.ssh/terraform.pub"
    }
```

## placeholder for the keys

```
~/.ssh/terraform.pub
resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer" {
  key_name   = "newssh"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa 
}
```

Comment: i see the following error while execution,                                                       aws_instance.web (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.web (remote-exec):   Host: xx.2xx.xx.247
aws_instance.web (remote-exec):   User: ec2-user
aws_instance.web (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.web (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.web (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
aws_instance.web (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your SSH key to your ssh-agent

Ensure ssh-agent is enabled and running in the background

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Add your SSH key to the ssh-agent. If you used an existing SSH key rather than generating a new SSH key, you’ll need to replace id_rsa in the command with the name of your existing private key file.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

so in your case

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/terraform
```

Then run terraform apply

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I was created with unsupported encryption.

*Create an RSA key. Amazon EC2 does not accept DSA keys*

You can have a look at this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html